# Loop over all (unordered) pairs of elements in a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

I have a `std::vector` of some data (Points in my case) and I want to loop over all distinct pairs of elements. The order of the pair is not important (as I am only interested in the distance of the points). With a classic `for` loop what I would want to do would be something like:

```
std::vector<double> vec{-1., 3., 5., -8., 123., ...};

for (std::vector<double>::size_type first = 0; first < vec.size(); ++first) {
    for (std::vector<double>::size_type second = first+1; second < vec.size();
         ++second) {
        // Compute something using std::fabs(vec.at(first)-vec.at(second))
    }
}
```

My question is now if one can achieve this more elegantly using range based loops.

Comment: I am not aware of a way to use range-based for loops here, but the code becomes more elegant by using iterators and `auto`.

Comment: Depending on what you intend to do inside the inner loop and if the output is in a form where doing an action between every combination of elements in a container could be a generic process, I'd be tempted to write an STL-like algorithm for this traversal strategy and put the inner-loop stuff in a lambda. With good function names it might be clearer.

Comment: @RyanP: might we see that "in the flesh"?

Comment: @RyanP Actually, the action inside the inner loop is quite complex so I am afraid this is not a good option for my specific case. Thus, I personally will go with Bathsheba's answer, I guess. Nonetheless, my question was left rather general on purpose hoping that other people might find it useful as well. So your suggestion might serve as a good answer to the question anyway.

Comment: If you happen to have a lot of those loops in your code you might consider writing a specific 'iterator' object that encapsulates the double loop.

Comment: Do you have duplicate numbers?

Comment: @MRB No there will be no duplicates. In my specific case the vector contains pointers to more complex objects not just doubles, btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't attempt to coerce it into a range based loop (since contriving the start of the inner loop will be tricky), but I would work directly with the iterators to clarify the loop body and to make the code less dependent on the specific container you're using:

```
for (auto first = vec.begin(); first != vec.end(); ++first){
    for (auto second = first + 1; second != vec.end(); ++second){
        // Your vec.at(first) is now simply *first.    
    }
}
```

Note that `first + 1` is always valid since `first` is never `vec.end()` when `first + 1` is evaluated.

`std::vector::at` is also required by the C++ standard to check that the supplied index is in the bounds of the vector (and throw a `std::out_of_range` exception if it isn't within the bounds), which is an unnecessary overhead in your case.

Answer (score 1):

> I provide this answer only because OP want a way of doing that with
>   range based for loops. It isn't more elegant than ordinary loops.

If your vector doesn't have duplicate numbers you can use reverse iteration instead of beginning from a specific point in the second loop, so that you can use range based for in your iterations.

for reverse iteration by range based for loops you want an adapter class.

```
template <typename It>
class reverse_adapter
{
public:
    reverse_adapter(It rbegin, It rend)
        : _rbegin(rbegin), _rend(rend)
    {}

    It begin() const { return _rbegin; }

    It end() const { return _rend; }

private:
    It _rbegin;
    It _rend;
};

template<typename Container>
reverse_adapter<typename Container::reverse_iterator> make_reverse(Container& container)
{
    reverse_adapter<typename Container::reverse_iterator> adapter(std::rbegin(container), std::rend(container));
    return adapter;
}
```

And use this adapter for reverse iteration in second loop.

```
for(auto val : vec)
{
    for (auto second_val : make_reverse(vec)) // Start from last to current item in first loop
    {
        if (val == second_val) break; // Instead of first + 1 in second loop

        auto dif = val - second_val;
    }
}
```